# Deleting cells based on conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of employees in column A, and their status (chosen from a dropdown menu, "Active" or "Inactive") in column B. They are in a sheet called "Employee List".

When an employee's status is set to "Inactive", I want to cut and paste the employee to another sheet automatically. The other sheet is called "Misc"

If this cannot be done automatically when the status is set to "Inactive", then maybe I can set a button that would invoke the VBA commands in that worksheet to clear all inactive employees from the list and move them to the other sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more hungry for reputation than Ben M here so I'll send you some code. :) You should still take his advice of course, and start reading good books.

The following could use some fine-tuning still, but should be a good starting point. If, as you wrote, you want Excel to automatically move the Employee Name and Status as soon as the Inactive choice is made, this should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Only react to edits in Column B:  '
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheets("Employee List").Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

        ' Dont do anything if > 1 cell was just changed:   '
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

            ' Only make the change if the new value in Col B is "inactive":    '
            If Target.Value = "Inactive" Then

                ' Find the next available cell on the Misc sheet for a name:   '
                Dim nextRange As Range
                Set nextRange = Sheets("Misc").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                ' Cut the employee name and status and paste onto the Misc sheet:   '
                Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, -1)).Cut
                Sheets("Misc").Paste       Destination:=Sheets("Misc").Range(nextRange.Address)

            End If
        End If

    End If


    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Notice that whenever you write code against an event, you probably need to disable events so Excel doesn't get into any sort of infinite loop.

Comment: @Peter Way to provide some code! I edited the comments in your VBA code a little bit to help with the way the code syntax is highlighted. Every time you use a `'` in your code, it highlights it out. So avoiding contractions such as `don't` in your comments and also add single quotes to the *end* of your line of comments.

Comment: Thanks Peter!
I will try implementing it in the next couple of days and tell you how it goes.
I've been given more time with this task, and I have been given more "urgent" work, so I'll try this maybe later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Whoo, works like a charm. Thanks a lot, Peter! One thing though - is there a(n easy) way to tidy up the list after this action takes effect? For example, say I set an employee in the middle of the list to "Inactive", it moves the employee out of the list, but now theres an empty row in the list. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, veol, I meant to warn you about that. There is a way but it's just more code. Do you want to take a stab at it, using the Macro recorded, or do you just want the code? Either way is OK with me.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Once of the best ways to get started in Excel VBA is to record Macros and look at the code they produce.  That way you'll see how you can manipulate objects in Excel using VBA code.

Also, consider getting [VBA Developer's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782119514).  It's based on older versions of Office, but VBA hasn't changed much (if at all) in the last view versions of Office, so it's still a good read.

Learn basic things like object instantiation, loops, conditional logic, string concatenation, etc. and that will take you a long way.

---

For your current problem, what you might do is record a macro of a cut and paste move and see what code it produces.  Then see if you can figure out how to modify that code to suit your purposes.

Come back to Stack Overflow and ask **very specific questions** if you get stuck and that's the bast way to get a good answer.  For example, you might say "how do I loop through my range of cells to apply this copy and paste?".

Comment: Thanks for the tips.
They have given me more time for the revamping of the spreadsheets, so I think I will take my time with it to learn some of the VBA language before I proceed. (Although I see someone has answered with some code below... tempting)
And I've been playing with "Record Macros", and its helped to automate some of the little things with excel, and it has helped a lot! Thanks :)